# Unable to use until method of WebDriverWait

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am getting following error:

`The method until(Function<? super WebDriver,V>) in the type FluentWait<WebDriver> is not applicable for the arguments (ExpectedCondition<Boolean>)`

My code is like this:

```
try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 60);
            wait.until(
                    ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div[class='ui-block']")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My pom.xml dependencies looks like this:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.48</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I tried to look for this error and got to know its due to guava dependency issue, I made it latest 25-jre and also 21. But no help. Can someone suggest a solution to it?

Comment: Can you please check with  guava version 23 and don’t use deprecated untill() method?

Comment: I tried that and even older ones, still no luck

Comment: Ok selenium change log recommended to use guava 23 from v3.5.1.  You can try this combination : guava v21 + selenium v 3.2.0  and jdk ver 8 as recommended here...   https://softwaretestingboard.com/q2a/1907/function-webdriver-fluentwait-webdriver-applicable-arguments#axzz68BFzmEjv

Comment: More or less, it seems compatibility issue.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, Thanks. It fixed the issue

Comment: I am posting it as answer so it will be helpful for people have same issue in future. Please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is compatibility issue. To solve it, you can use Guava version 21 + selenium version 3.2.0 + JDK 8.

For more details you can check below link:

https://softwaretestingboard.com/q2a/1907/function-webdriver-fluentwait-webdriver-applicable-arguments#axzz68BFzmEjv

I hope it will help you.